# how to add patch-here to a list in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Or how can I add coordinates to a patch-set?
I want to create a list and add each patch visited as another element of the list (using lput) but instead the list replaces the patch-here everytime, thus I tried to use patch-set, however I don't know how to add new patches in the end of it and add coordinates there.

Here is my code so far:

```
globals [ frontier frontier2 ]

breed [squares square]
breed [circles circle]

to setup
  ca
  set-default-shape squares "square"
  set-default-shape circles "circle"
  create-breeds
  reset-ticks
end

to create-breeds
    create-squares 1 [
      setxy 0 0  ]
    create-circles 1 [
      setxy 5 5 ]
end

to go
  ask squares [
    fd 1
    set frontier []
    set frontier lput patch-here frontier
    show frontier
  ]
  ask circles [
    fd 1
    set frontier2 patch-set patch-here
    show frontier2
  ]
  tick
end
```

And that's what the command center is showing:

"(square 0): [(patch 7 -3)]

(circle 1): (agentset, 1 patch)"

I was expecting something like (square 0): [(patch 0 0) (patch 1 0) (patch 2 0)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It replaces the patch every time because you're explicitly reinitializing the list every time within your `go` procedure with:

```
set frontier []
```

Just move that line into your `setup` procedure instead!

As for adding a patch to a patch set instead of a list, the correct syntax would have been:

```
set frontier2 (patch-set frontier2 patch-here)
```

But I don't suggest you use that because it needs to rebuild the patch set every time and is thus slower than using a list and `lput`. Also, a patch set is always accessed in random order, which I suspect is not what you want here.